# Pandas Dataframe lookup

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lookup

I have a pandas dataframe that looks something like this

| Category | Parent Category | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | Foo |
| 4 | 1 | Bar |
| 5 | 9 | Fizz |
| 1 | 0 | Buzz |
| 9 | 0 | Foobar |

I'm looking for an elegant solution (without looping over the `iteritems()` which does the following:
For every Category with a parent category: replace the number of the parent category in a row (`row1`)  by a look up for a row (`row2`)with the category number equaling the other rows parent category and its own parent category equaling 0.

E.g. the df should look like this after the lookup:

| Category | Parent Category | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Buzz | Foo |
| 4 | Buzz | Bar |
| 5 | Foobar | Fizz |
| 1 | 0 | Buzz |
| 9 | 0 | Foobar |

What is the best end most "pandas-like" way of doing this lookup?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a dictionary where they key is the category and the value is the description, you can use `map` on the `Parent Category` to do the replacement.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Category': {0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 1, 4: 9},
 'Parent Category': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 9, 3: 0, 4: 0},
 'Description': {0: 'Foo', 1: 'Bar', 2: 'Fizz', 3: 'Buzz', 4: 'Foobar'}})

df['Parent Category'] = df['Parent Category'].map(df.set_index('Category')['Description'].to_dict()).fillna(0)
```

Output

```
   Category Parent Category Description
0         2            Buzz         Foo
1         4            Buzz         Bar
2         5          Foobar        Fizz
3         1               0        Buzz
4         9               0      Foobar
```